# Confirm meaning of phrase 隙を与える

Tags: translation

The phrase in the title, 「隙を与える」, comes from 佐賀のがばいばあちゃん p. 167, ch. 13.

The full sentence is 「ばあちゃんは、泥棒に改心する隙を与えてるの。」 (I don't have a Japanese IME on this computer. As it's a public computer, I can't install one.) This is quoted text; the speaker is the ばあちゃん in question.

My reading of the sentence is: I will give the burglar an opportunity to change their mind (i.e. not rob the house).

Is this correct. Does the 隙を与える mean 'give an opportunity'. Please clarify.

Comment: BTW you can use web-based IMEs like Google's or [this](http://ajaxime.chasen.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I couldn't figure out how to get the IME to scroll through kanji selections. However, I did find this site: http://www.inputking.com/ime/ime_new.php. That one allows you to input kana and kanji easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 泥棒{どろぼう}に改心{かいしん}する隙{すき}を与{あた}えてるの。
>   I will give the burglar an opportunity to change their mind.

**Edited:**

Close!
The pronoun of the sentence is ばあちゃん, so it would be interpreted like:

> *Granny is giving the thief a chance or an opportunity to mend their ways.*

---

**Original:**

Close!
Why do you think the 泥棒 is the plural form?

*Granny is giving the thief a chance or an opportunity to repent his past.*

I think, she can have enough power to change only one man's mind, but not a group of thieves.

Comment: I don't think Robert implied anywhere he's talking about multiple burglars.

Comment: I don't know the whole story of gabai-baachan, but only from this sentence it's natural to think the 泥棒 is single not multiple.

Comment: I'm talking about you saying "Why do you think the 泥棒 is the plural form?" - nowhere in the question plural is used.

Comment: Maybe mackygoo is concerned about the use of *their* before *mind*? This is called [singular they](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they), and this *their* does not mean the speaker thinks there are more than one person.

Comment: BTW, does 改心する really mean *repent his past*? seems a bit of a stretch to me.

Comment: @naruto: I know *they* is commonly used instead of he/she. It's my blame that I thought 泥棒 was a male.

Comment: @Igor Skochinsky: I used the phrase "to repent one's past" instead of "to change one's mind for the better".

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky: In my dictionary, *repent* is defined as a formal word and the meaning of it is *to sorry for and wish one had not done (something bad) : He repented his wickedness, I have nothing to repent of. He repented having shot the bird.* 
From this definition to repent for his past seems not too strict for 改心する, but, I admit, it is lack of the nuance of changing one's mind.

Comment: @naruto Yes, well spotted. I used the singular they because a 'he' would be considered rude/presumptive and 'he/she' or 'he or she' is not comfortable to read. But I realise this part of the discussion is over.

Comment: @mackygoo Sorry; I probably wasn't clear enough in the question. I had to rush as my computer had a time limit. The whole quote is direct speech https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_speech. The speaker is the granny in question. She is referring to herself as ばあちゃん; that's why I translated it as 'I....' I see that you could also translate it with 'Granny' as the subject. I was more concerned with trying to understand the general sense of the sentence.

Comment: Thanks, @mackygoo. Your answer clarifies what I wanted to find out. I checked 改心 in the dictionary. 'Repent their past,' could work as a translation but probably comes across as too strong in the context. 'Mend their ways,' is a much better fit, I think. I originally guessed, 'Change their mind,' which seemed to fit the text. The thief would guess that getting into the house was too easy, so there must be a trick to this 「裏がある」. Presumably, they would 'change their mind'. But perhaps 'mend their ways,' works better - I don't know. In any case, ばあちゃん is quite eccentric sometimes.